# Concept of direct limit

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

So I was going through exercise of Atiyah McDonald. And there they introduced concept of direct limit of modules,at first I really understood nothing. But upon searching further I came up with general  definitions of direct limits. Although still now I really have so many questions left. It will be great if anyone can explain to me or can suggest me good article on direct limit. And another question is, why this is called direct limit. I mean is there any similarities between the standard definition th at we use of limit to this one. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also some good first examples to play around with: show that a set is the direct limit of its finite sets ordered by inclusion, an abelian group is the direct limit of its f.g. subgroups. If you know what sheaves are computing some stalks of some first examples of sheaves, etc

Comment: The categorical generalization of a "direct limit" is a [colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimit) (though often, specifically a [filtered colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit)). The terminology gets somewhat unfortunate as the dual to a "direct limit" is an "inverse limit" which is called just a [limit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limit) in category theory.